# gradle execute process error stream

Tags: android, groovy, android-emulator, gradle

I have an android project and trying to start the emulator. It works fine locally, but not on the build server, so I'm trying to figure out why, but I'm not able to see any of the error output (even locally).

```
task startEmulator << {
    def process = "emulator -avd nexus4 -no-boot-anim -no-window".execute()
    //...consumption code here
}
```

Here's what I tried for reading the error output:

```
process.waitFor()
print process.err.text
```

and

```
process.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

and

```
process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

and

```
process.consumeProcessErrorStream(System.err)
```

The error code gets set properly to 1 or 0 depending on whether the run was successful. It's not a matter of the code exiting too soon. For example when I try the code with an AVD name that doesn't exist, the error stream is empty.

What am I missing?

PS: Can't use an exec task since I need this execute call to be asynchronous/in the background.

Comment: Is the problem specific to `emulator` command? Could you try something simpler, like `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tomcat user (if you are using a tomcat) has the privileges to run the command emulator. If tomcat user doesn´t have the privileges, you are not going to be able to run the command.

Comment: I updated the question, I can't see anything on the error stream even locally. Also, I'm not looking for suggestions on how to fix the emulator problem - rather trying to understand why I can't read the error stream in gradle (notice the title of the question).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use a string buffer.

```
def bout = new StringBuffer()
// Not sure if a common buffer is always a good idea.
"ls".execute().waitForProcessOutput(bout, bout)
println bout.toString()
```